# String labels for classification

Tags: classification, scikit-learn

I've recently started playing SciKit ML. I just got my hands on classification algorithms (SGDClassifier, LinearSVC) and I'm not sure how to properly represent feature labels.

Suppose I'm trying to predict a football match outcome. Given `N` features the result is either `1=WIN` or `X=DRAW` or `2=LOSS`. Can/should I label my features using string values?

Eg.:

```
X_train = [[n0, n1, …, nn], …]
y_train = ['1', 'X', '2', …]
```

Or maybe I should use boolean matrices instead, like `[win,draw,loss]`, eg:

```
y_train = [[1,0,0], [0,1,0], [0,0,1], …]
```

Or maybe I should use a single digit to map each label `1=win` and `0=draw`, `-1=loss`, eg:

```
y_train = [1, 0, -1]
```

**Which one would be best to pick and why?** I'm a newbie, thank you for your patience.

Answer (score 1):

Mutually exclusive classes are usually integers; in your case, win=0, draw=1, loss=2 (for instance).

It is mostly a convention and is convenient for implementation.